# CMake find package files, how are the config files used?

Tags: cmake

I have a project that uses a 3rd party library (let's call it `somelib`) for which I wrote a cmake file to search for it.

This is the `somelibConfig.cmake` file I wrote and placed in `/usr/local/lib/cmake/somelib/`:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(somelib_LIBRARY somelib
    PATHS /usr/local/lib
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
SET(somelib_LIBRARIES ${somelib_LIBRARY})
FIND_PATH(somelib_INCLUDE_DIR somelib.hpp
    PATHS /usr/local/include/somelib
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
SET(somelib_INCLUDE_DIRS ${somelib_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Then, if I do `find_package(somelib REQUIRED)` it works ok.

However, if I move and rename `somelibConfig.cmake` to `myproject/CMakeModules/Findsomelib.cmake` (this directory is added to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`), after `find_package` I see that variables `somelib_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `somelib_LIBRARY` are correctly filled, but `somelib_FOUND` is not set (and even so, `find_package` does not abort the compilation).

Is that `*Config.cmake` valid for a `Find*.cmake`?

How is it possible that all the variables but the `*_FOUND` one are set?

Why does not `find_package` with `REQUIRED` abort the compilation if `*_FOUND` is not set?

Answer (score 5):

Config files and find-modules are fundamentally different.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

Only the developers of somelib ship a config file (if they do). If they don't, then you need to write a find-module to find somelib. Such a find-module should not be copied to /usr/local as you did. Just keep it with your project and ask the somelib developers to ship a config file instead. config files shipped by upstream is superior to find modules written by you. It doesn't matter if somelib upstream does not use cmake. Both Qt and LLVM ship config files when using non-cmake buildsystems.

One example of inferiority is that when writing a find-module you need to set the _FOUND variable. More information about writing find-modules is here:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#manual:cmake-developer%287%29

Comment: @ruslo, The primary buildsystem of LLVM/Clang is hand-written makefiles. Those hand-written makefiles were patched to generate cmake config files over multiple revisions, including r201053.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching in default library folder your parameters should not contain NO_DEFAULT_PATH.

Try this,

```
SET(libraryName "somelibrary.so") #in linux .a or .so
FIND_LIBRARY(LIBRARY ${libraryName}
    PATHS "/usr/local/lib/cmake/somelib/"
)
MESSAGE("library path ${LIBRARY})
```

If this was successful, LIBRARY_FOUND will be set.

P.S: Note the quotes